# d3 animation wordCloud flyin

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

i am trying to make a simple animation in d3 (i am new to it). i have made a word cloud presentation, and i will like it to "fly in" (small movement from left to right and then in center) when the page opens.

```
var text = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 1200)
            .attr("height", 800)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(550,300)")
            .selectAll("text")
            .data(words)
            .enter().append("text")
            .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
            .style("font-family", "Impact")
            .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
            })
            .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
```

Comment: Set the initial position to be off the page to the left, then add a transition to the desired end position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is set the initial position to be off the page to the left, then add a transition to the desired end position. For example:

```
d3.select("svg > g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(-550,300)")
  .transition()
  .attr("transform", "translate(550,300)");
```